# javascript for loop "jump over value"

Tags: javascript, parameters, for-loop, return

hi guys I have a small piece of code in jquery and I have a problem. It seems that for loop jumps over the second parameter ( when i = 2), can you tell me what's wrong?

here is code:

```
    var items = $(".item").length;
    var currentIndex = items;

    place(currentIndex);

    function place(index){
        var s1 = Math.floor(items / 2);

        for (i = 1; i <= items; i++){
            (function(i, index){

                if (i <= s1){
                    var id = findNext(1, i);
                    console.log("i = " + i + " > id = " + id);
                } else if ( i > s1){
                    console.log("i = " + i);
                }

            })(i, index);
        }
    }

    function findNext(index, times){
        var result = index;

        for (i = 1; i <= times; i++){
            if (result == items){
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result ++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

console output shows this :

```
i = 1 > id = 2
i = 3
i = 4
```

so it seems that for loop jumps over the second parameter (when i = 2) can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your primary loop inside the function `place`, you define a global variable `i`. You do the same inside `findNext` thus overwriting the original `i` variable. Define `i` using the `var` keyword so it is only accessible inside the scope in which it was created.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= items; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`var id = findNext(1, i);` assignment returns 3 when `i=2` because of scooping.
Please refer this link: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/